# how does the concept of id's work in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How does the concept of id's work in Firebase? If I insert an array of json objects into a table then Firebase assigns 0-based Id's by default. For example, if I add the following array as a value for Products:

```
[
{
"Id": 123,
"Name": "my-product-1",
"Price": 9.99
},
{
"Id": 124,
"Name": "my-product-2",
"Price": 24.99
}
]
```

Then, I would retrieve "my-product-1" from the array above as:

```
firebase.database().ref('Products/0')
```

So it looks like the concept of a record id in Firebase is based on insert order as opposed to a discrete Id record property.  Is this correct?  Is there a way to configure the rest calls to be 1-based instead of 0-based?  I can see how some people might be uncomfortable accessing a record by an Id of 0 in a rest call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inserting an array, then you are accessing by array's index instead of the id you are passing.

If you want to access by id, you need to insert the id as the key of the object.

```
{
  "123": {
    "Id": 123,
    "Name": "my-product-1",
    "Price": 9.99
  },
  "124": {
    "Id": 124,
    "Name": "my-product-2",
    "Price": 24.99
  }
}
```

The id from within is optional.